# NavigationBar of UIPageViewController not displaying title

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Navigation Bar of UIPageViewController is not displaying page numbers as title of nav bar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

//modelArray holds the page numbers
modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int index = 1; index <= totalPages; index++) {

    [modelArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index]];

}

UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 45)];

navBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:164.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

self.navigationItem.title = modelArray;

[self displayPageNumber:1];

thePageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

thePageViewController.delegate = self;
thePageViewController.dataSource = self;

thePageViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];
contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:contentViewController];
[thePageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:thePageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:thePageViewController.view];
thePageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


[thePageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

_toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 960, self.view.bounds.size.width, 45)];

_toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

_toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:164.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

 [self.view addSubview:_toolbar];

[self.view addSubview:navBar];
 }

  - (void) pageViewController:(PageViewController *)pageViewController willTurnToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)pageIndex {
[self displayPageNumber:pageIndex + 1];
}


   - (void) displayPageNumber:(NSUInteger)pageNumber {
self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"Page %u of %u",
                             pageNumber,
                             CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)];
     }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple.

Do it this way

```
_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 45)];

_navBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:164.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

UINavigationItem *title = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                                   @"Page %i of %i",
                                                                   pageNumber,
                                                                   CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(thePDF)]];
[_navBar pushNavigationItem:title animated:NO];
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you create navBar, add it to subview, but changing `self.navigationItem`. As I see in your code, these are different navigation bars. Try saving your `navBar` into some `strong` property and changing `navBar` instead of `self.navigationItem`

P.S. In this line `self.navigationItem.title = modelArray;` you assigning an NSMutableArray to NSString. That's bad :)

Comment: i just tried this but still not working self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
         @"Page %u of %u", 
         pageNumber, 
         CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf)];

Comment: No, try to do as I said later: "Try saving your `navBar` into some `strong` property and changing `navBar` instead of `self.navigationItem`".

Comment: Now i have strong property of navBar and tried like this  _navBar.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                    @"Page %u of %u",
                    pageNumber,
                    CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)];
    
but there is no title property in object of type UINavigationBar

Answer (score 1):

If you see only orange `navBar`, then your `self.navigationItem` just not showing. You need your `viewController` to be a child of `navigationController` like there:
[image]

If you do that, then you can write `self.navigationItem.title = @"123";` like here:
[image]

and you will get result you want:
[image]

**UPD:** Or you can do in that way:

```
@interface MCViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationItem *navItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationBar *navBar;

@end

@implementation MCViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST"];
    self.navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    self.navBar.items = @[self.navItem];
    [self.view addSubview:self.navBar];
}

@end
```

And after that change `title` property of `navItem`.

Comment: how to do it programmtically

Comment: well, you can create navigation controller with your controller as rootViewController like this: http://d.pr/i/cUKY
`navigationController` is a `strong` property in `appDelegate`.